# If $f,g: \mathbb R_{> 0} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are convex, is $\frac{f(x)+g(y)}{x+y}$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

My question is a bit more specific than the title. Suppose we have functions $f,g$ that are of the form

$$f(x) = \int_0^x h_f(u)\ du~,$$
and
$$g(x) = \int_0^x h_g(u)\ du~,$$
for some nondecreasing and integrable (but not necessarily continuous) functions $h_f: [0,B_f] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $h_g: [0,B_g] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ for some real numbers $0 < B_f, B_g < \infty$.

Then, because $h_f$ and $h_g$ are nondecreasing, $f$ and $g$ are convex (as functions from $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ to $\mathbb R$).

Now my question is whether $\frac{f(x)+g(y)}{x+y}$, restricted to be a function from $\mathbb R_{>0}^2$ to $\mathbb R$, is also convex?

I believe it is true that the functions $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and $\frac{g(x)}{x}$ are convex over the positive real line. I am wondering if this "extension" is also true? This "feels" like it should be true, but I am having a hard time pinning it down...

Edit: I was hoping this would be true for convex functions in general, but as pointed out by Martin in the comments, this is not the case

Comment: Your initial conjecture is already wrong: $f(x) = x-1$ is convex, but $f(x)/x$ is not.

Comment: Great catch - let me modify this into a more specific question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is wrong. The functions
$$
 f(x) =  g(x) =  \int_0^x \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} \, du= \sqrt{1+x^2} - 1
$$
are of the given form, but
$$
 h(x, y) = \frac{f(x)+g(y)}{x+y}
$$
is not convex on $\Bbb R_{>0}^2$ because
$$
 h(x, x) = \frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}
$$
is not convex on $\Bbb R_{>0}$.